# How to get a `td` text under a specific `th` in a table with Jsoup?

Tags: jsoup

Following is the extracted rows from a table;

```
<table class="infobox vevent" style="width:22em">
<caption class="summary">Adobe Shockwave Player</caption>
<tr> 
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><a href="/wiki/File:Adobe_Shockwave_Player_logo.png" class="image"><img alt="Adobe Shockwave Player logo.png" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/8e/Adobe_Shockwave_Player_logo.png/64px-Adobe_Shockwave_Player_logo.png" width="64" height="64" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/8e/Adobe_Shockwave_Player_logo.png/96px-Adobe_Shockwave_Player_logo.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/8e/Adobe_Shockwave_Player_logo.png/128px-Adobe_Shockwave_Player_logo.png 2x" data-file-width="165" data-file-height="165"></a></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
 <th scope="row" style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Software_developer" title="Software developer">Original author(s)</a></th> 
 <td><a href="/wiki/Macromedia" title="Macromedia">Macromedia</a></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
 <th scope="row" style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Software_developer" title="Software developer">Developer(s)</a></th> 
 <td><a href="/wiki/Adobe_Systems" title="Adobe Systems">Adobe Systems</a></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
 <th scope="row" style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle" title="Software release life cycle">Stable release</a></th> 
 <td>12.2.4.194 / 19&nbsp;February 2016<span class="noprint">; 4 months ago</span><span style="display:none">&nbsp;(<span class="bday dtstart published updated">2016-02-19</span>)</span><sup id="cite_ref-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-1">[1]</a></sup></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
 <th scope="row" style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Operating_system" title="Operating system">Operating system</a></th> 
 <td><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Windows" title="Microsoft Windows">Microsoft Windows</a>, <a href="/wiki/Mac_OS_9" title="Mac OS 9">Mac OS 9</a>, <a href="/wiki/Mac_OS_X" class="mw-redirect" title="Mac OS X">Mac OS X</a> (Universal)</td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
 <th scope="row" style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Computing_platform" title="Computing platform">Platform</a></th> 
 <td><a href="/wiki/Web_browsers" class="mw-redirect" title="Web browsers">Web browsers</a></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
 <th scope="row" style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/List_of_software_categories" title="List of software categories">Type</a></th> 
 <td>Multimedia Player / <a href="/wiki/MIME" title="MIME">MIME</a> type: application/x-director</td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
 <th scope="row" style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="/wiki/Software_license" title="Software license">License</a></th> 
 <td><a href="/wiki/Proprietary_software" title="Proprietary software">Proprietary</a><sup id="cite_ref-2" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-2">[2]</a></sup></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
 <th scope="row" style="white-space: nowrap;">Website</th> 
 <td><span class="url"><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.adobe.com/products/shockwaveplayer/">www<wbr>.adobe<wbr>.com<wbr>/products<wbr>/shockwaveplayer<wbr>/</a></span></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to get:

**1.** td's text "12.2.4.194" under a specific th's text "Stable release".
  **2.** td's text "Microsoft Windows" under a specific th's text "Operating System".

I am stuck with the below code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();
for (Element table : doc.select("table.infobox")) {
    String strName = table.getElementsByTag("caption").text();
    if (strName.toLowerCase().contains("shockwave player")) {
        Elements trow = table.select("tr");
        System.out.println(trow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include what you've tried so far and what specific problems you have with your implementation. We're not a coding service

Comment: Have updated my main question as asked for.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an error? an exception? does it not do what you expect? (if so, what *do* you expect and how is that different from what it currently does?) Refer to *[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*

Comment: No errors.
I started with this script and I am just able to go till getting the rows from my desired table with a text from a caption and validating if the caption text matches as I need and then hunt for the specific data under specific <th>.
Just I need a way to get the data as I asked in point 1 and 2 exactly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS query:

```
table.infobox tr:has(a:containsOwn(Stable release))    > td,
table.infobox tr:has(a:containsOwn(Microsoft Windows)) > td
```

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/~kIZNfK8FBzEw1pFFS9NYIeivJ9A)

#### Sample code:

```
public static String getTDtext(Element table, String headerText) {
    Element td = table.select("tr:has(a:containsOwn(" + headerText + ")) > td").first();

    if (td==null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find text for " + headerText);
    } else {
        return td.ownText();
    }
}
```

#### Discussion:

```
tr                           /* Select tr elements ...                 */
:has(                        /* ... having ...                         */
   a                         /* ... an anchor element ...              */
   :containsOwn(headerText)  /* ... containing headerText ...          */
)
> td                         /* Select all td elements direct children */
```

#### References:

- [Jsoup CSS selector syntax](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)
- [Element#ownText](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--)

Comment: Thanks for the sample!!